# C++ file(s) and header seem to be properly coded, but cannot call function from another file?

Tags: c++

I have two c++ files, one of which has a header file with a function declaration in it. I am attempting to call that function from another c++ file, however I get an error saying "expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ';' token".

File 1-

```
#include <iostream>
#include "fileTwo.h"
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    return 0;
}

someFunction();
```

File 2-

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int someFunction()
{
    cout << "Hello" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

File 2 header-

```
#ifndef FILETWO_H_INCLUDED
#define FILETWO_H_INCLUDED

int someFunction();

#endif // FILETWO_H_INCLUDED
```

Note that file 2 and the header file for file 2 have the same name, fileTwo.cpp and fileTwo.h

Comment: Put the actual file names above the code snippets, please. Also, you can't just call a function out of nowhere like you do below your main function. That call should be in the main function.

Answer (score 1):

> I am attempting to call that function

You should do this, then:

```
int main()
{
    someFunction();
    return 0;
}
```

When you put the "call" globally, the compiler expects a defintiion or declaration.

Comment: I tried this and still got an error, I then tried including File 2's own header inside of File 2 but it still doesn't work?

Comment: You should post the whole output from the build.

Comment: Here is the build, Jeffery. ||=== Build: Debug in c++Two (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
c:\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\..\..\..\..\mingw32\bin\ld.exe: obj\Debug\main.o||in function `main':|
C:\c++Two\main.cpp|8|undefined reference to `someFunction()'|
||error: ld returned 1 exit status|
||=== Build failed: 2 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|

Comment: @RyanSmith: the error implies that you are compiling the files separately without telling the compiler that that is what you are doing. You can either specify the `-c` option to compile the two `.cpp` files separate and produce two object file ( I *guess* `*.obj` on your system) and link them in a separste step. Alternatively you can specify both `.cpp` files when compiling.

Comment: Dietmar Kühl, this worked. I am using CodeBlocks and I changed the project settings to compile all files at once. Thank you!